# Is it possible to run Java program from command line without compiling?

Tags: java, cmd

I have a set of instructions to create a Java application that takes multiple arguments when running the application from a CMD line.

The instructions state:

> Thus, using the example set of above, assuming the main() method of your program is in a class called JavaClassName, the output should be:

```
$ java JavaClassName 4 7 file.csv
program output here
```

My question is:

Isn't this skipping the compile process?
Would they assume that loading the Java classes onto a computer that has never run this application before (or a directory with purely the `.java` files needed to run); running the cmd

```
$ java JavaClassName 4 7 file.csv
```

would output something?

Sidenote: Currently, running that CMD outputs

```
Error: Could not find or load main class JavaClassName
```

Have ran through multiple SO questions and online tutorials trying to get this to even run but I have yet to get it to work.

Comment: If you give them the compiled class files, they should run with that command.  What filetype are they asking for?  If they ask for the source code, they probably know how to compile it and it's implied

Comment: The example isn't in a class called JavaClassName if it is in a ".java" file. Yes, you must compile ".java" files to be ".class" files (and then you can package those in a ".jar" file) before you can run it with Java. Try `javac -cp . JavaClassName.java` and then your example command.

Comment: They are asking for the files submitted in a zip file, so I assume the compiled class files, as well as the source .java files

Comment: Just include the java and class files in your submission, if their process is to compile the source code, then your class files will be overwritten and no harm done.  If they don't compile your source code, then the class files will still be there ready to run

Comment: This is also why it's common to use/request a make file with run and compile targets

Comment: @phflack yes, that sounds good to me. I asked the question originally as I have never had to compile or run Java from the cmd line before, so did not know the correct standards in doing so. I suppose no matter what I send, they will be able to get it to run in their workspace before running it anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ask:

> Isn't this skipping the compile process?

Absolutely yes. A command line like `java JavaClassName 4 7 file.csv` assumes that there is a compiled class file "JavaClassName.class" in the current directory (or in some other directory or Zip/Jar file found in the CLASSPATH environment variable). And yes, to produce that "JavaClassName.class" class file, you have to use a java compiler first.

Answer (score 2):

from Java 10 **it is possible** to run java programs that fit a single file without manually run the compiler first.
It will be compiled on the fly before execution. Nice and useful for scripting.

e.g. writing HelloWorld.java file

```
public class HelloWorld{
  public static void main(String[] args) { 
        System.out.println("Hello World");
  }
}
```

we can run it as

```
java HelloWorld.java
```

We can also add more classes in the single file.

---

from Java 11 we can also use **shebang** files

- we have to specify which version of the java language you want to use
- we have to save the file without `.java` extension
- remember to give executable permissions `chmod +x HelloWorld`

writing HelloWorld file

```
#!/path/to/java --source 11

public class HelloWorld{
  public static void main(String[] args) { 
        System.out.println("Hello World");
  }
}
```

and we can run it as

```
./HelloWorld
```